# iOS tableHeaderView in UITableViewController never displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement a tableViewHeader (and not "viewForHeaderInSection") for my tableview in a `UITableViewController` "TBVC1".

I tried two solution (don't work of course...):

1ST : Added a UIView in the top of my `UITableViewController` in my storyboard. If I add a `UILabel` (with constraints etc) in this `UIView`, and try to display my View TBVC1.... I see nothing. The full View is empty. But, if I delete the UILabel inserted in the header `UIView`, I can see all my cells and the headerView background Color...

Do you have any idea why I can't put any UI component in this `UIView`?

2ND : If I try load a specific nib `UIView` like this :

```
Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Title", owner: nil, options: nil)!.first as! UIView
self.tableView.setTableHeaderView(headerView: customView)
self.tableView.updateHeaderViewFrame()



 extension UITableView {

/// Set table header view & add Auto layout.
func setTableHeaderView(headerView: UIView) {
    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // Set first.
    self.tableHeaderView = headerView

    // Then setup AutoLayout.
    headerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
}

/// Update header view's frame.
func updateHeaderViewFrame() {
    guard let headerView = self.tableHeaderView else { return }

    // Update the size of the header based on its internal content.
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    // ***Trigger table view to know that header should be updated.
    let header = self.tableHeaderView
    self.tableHeaderView = header
}
}
```

it doesn't work too... my full View is empty...

Do you have any ideas why I don't succeed to display a simple `UILabel` in my `UIView` for the `tableViewheader`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my way is proper, but every time I set `tableHeaderView`, I also set its height manually.

If you want to use auto-layout in your `tableHeaderView`, you can call `systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)` on the header view to get the calculated size and assign the height to headerView.

You can try this simple example in Playground.

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = .red

        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .white

        headerView.addSubview(label)

        let attributes: [NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute] = [.leading, .top, .centerX, .centerY]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(attributes.map {
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: $0, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: $0, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        })
        // We have to set height manually, so use `systemLayoutSizeFitting` to get the layouted height
        headerView.frame.size.height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize).height

        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```